# How to Make Soundcloud Custom Player's Tracklist Showing as The Info Toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, soundcloud

I'm working on the Soundcloud Custom Player, trying to make it look like the original Soundcloud Artwork Player that we all know is build in Flash that is not supported in iOS. All nearly done. You can look at what I've managed to do here - [MY TEST PLAYER](http://bassline.bg/music/test/)

I had to remove the hover elements cause it turns out that iOS has problems with that too, turning it can't play the audio due to the hover elements - these were the waveform, the volume control and the playing track time. Actually not problem with that. And it works like a charm.

Now at the bottom of my test player you can see the tracklist, that is actually scrollable. But I don't want to be shown always. If I make it to show on hover the player won't work in iOS which brings me back to where I started. So the only option left is to make the tracklist to show just like the Info Toggle in the upper left corner. So when you click it, to display the tracklist, just like when you click the Info it shows you the info for the current track.

I have to admit I'm not good in javascript at all. So first of all I have no idea is it possible. I looked carefully at `sc-player.js` file and did some tries... Found out that the Info Toggle is displaying with a command at line 506

```
.append('<a href="#info" class="sc-info-toggle">Info</a>')
```

Then I tried to add same code for the tracklist that looked something like that

```
.append('<a href="#tracklist" class="sc-tracklist-toggle">Tracklist</a>')
```

Of course giving the `sc-tracklist-toggle` custom CSS values. It works like a charm... The Tracklist Toggle appeared just like the Info Toggle, BUT nothing happens when I click it. Of course it wouldn't. And here is my problem. It is clear that `#tracklist` link I entered is not working and I don't know is it even possible to work like that. I tried to look over the file to see how the `#info` link is constructed but, as I previously said I'm not good at javascript at all so no luck!

Is it possible to call the tracklist just like the Info Toggle? And if it is, how to do that? Any help would be appreciated!

I'm using Soundcloud Custom Player, SC Player Standard, Structure - Vertical, Colors - Blue.
The html code that I'm using to show the player is:

```
<a href="https://soundcloud.com/basslinebg/sets/get-physical-presents-full" class="sc-player"></a>
```

Thanks in advance!